# Pygame, Changing scenes with new player x,y makes the player not move because its in a loop, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, pygame

As the title suggests if I change scenes with a new player position it gets stuck because its in the loop I understand why its happening I just don't know how to make it move with its new position, I have tried player.x,player.y = new x and new y but it goes to the location and gets stuck, there is a player class and also a scene class I think thats where the problem lies, I am still a beginner and im surprised I got this far, help is appreciated thank you!

```
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import time

pygame.init()
display_w = 1024
display_h = 768

world = pygame.Surface((2500, 2500))  # 2550, 2500
window = pygame.display.set_mode((display_w, display_h), HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF | RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("game_icon.png").convert_alpha())
pygame.display.set_caption("Work in progress")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("PressStart2P.ttf", 30, False)
tiles = pygame.image.load("Tile_set.png")
tiles1 = pygame.image.load("Tile_set1.png")

background = [
    pygame.image.load("background.png").convert(),
    pygame.image.load("background1.png").convert(),
]
black = 0, 0, 0
blue = 0, 0, 255


class Player(object):
    """The controllable player in game"""

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, speed):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprite_sheet.png").convert_alpha()
        self.speed = speed
        self.timer = 0
        self.frames = 1
        self.animation_direction = 2
        self.rect = self.image.subsurface(0, 0, 28, 45)
        self.interact = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 10, 10)
        self.shadow = tiles.subsurface(363, 468, 31, 19)
        self.pos_x, self.pos_y = 105, 77

    def animation(self):
        x_coord = 50 * self.frames
        y_coord = 50 * self.animation_direction
        self.character = self.image.subsurface(x_coord, y_coord, self.width, self.height).convert_alpha()
        self.timer += 0
        if self.timer >= 10:
            self.timer = 0
            self.frames += 1
            if self.frames >= 9:
                self.frames = 1

    def movement(self,):
        self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or self.keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.x -= self.speed
            self.pos_x += player.speed
            self.animation_direction = 1
            self.timer += 2
        if self.keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or self.keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.x += self.speed
            self.pos_x -= player.speed
            self.animation_direction = 3
            self.timer += 2
        if self.keys[pygame.K_UP] or self.keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.y -= self.speed
            self.pos_y += player.speed
            self.animation_direction = 0
            self.timer += 2
        if self.keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or self.keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.y += self.speed
            self.pos_y -= player.speed
            self.animation_direction = 2
            self.timer += 2

    def interaction(self):
        if self.keys[pygame.K_e] or self.keys[pygame.K_x]:
            if self.animation_direction == 1:
                self.interact = pygame.Rect(self.x - 15, self.y, 30, 40)
            if self.animation_direction == 3:
                self.interact = pygame.Rect(self.x + 15, self.y, 30, 40)
            if self.animation_direction == 0:
                self.interact = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y - 15, 30, 40)
            if self.animation_direction == 2:
                self.interact = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y + 15, 30, 40)

    def draw(self):
        world.blit(self.shadow, (self.x, self.y + 35))
        world.blit(self.character, (self.x, self.y))


player = Player(375, 275, 30, 50, 3.5)



class Door:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.image = tiles.subsurface(pygame.Rect(328, 432, width, height))
        # self.rect = self.image.subsurface(0, 0, 32, 32)

    def draw(self):
        world.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


door = Door(368, 35, 32, 64)


class Tree:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height = x, y, width, height
        self.image = (pygame.transform.scale(tiles.subsurface(pygame.Rect(99, 147, self.width, self.height)), (62, 82)))

    def amount(self):
        for y in range(0, 1650, 50):
            world.blit(self.image, (0, y))
        for y in range(0, 1650, 50):
            world.blit(self.image, (45, y))
        for y in range(0, 1650, 50):
            world.blit(self.image, (90, y))

    def draw(self):
        world.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


tree = Tree(230, 35, 48, 58)

door_list = [
    pygame.Rect(door.x, door.y, door.width, door.height),
]
sprite_list = [
    pygame.Rect(tree.x, tree.y, tree.width, tree.height),
    pygame.Rect(0, 0, 1000, 1),
    pygame.Rect(0, 0, 1, 1000),
    pygame.Rect(800, 0, 1, 1000),
    pygame.Rect(0, 600, 1000, 1),
    pygame.Rect(0, 0, 800, 64)
    # grass.rect.get_rect(topleft=(grass.x, grass.y)),
]

tree_list = [pygame.Rect(tree.x, tree.y, tree.width, tree.height),
             ]


class Scene:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sceneNum = 1

    def Scene_1(self):
        window.fill(black)
        window.blit(world, (player.pos_x, player.pos_y))
        world.blit(background[0], (0, 0))
        player_pos = (player.x, player.y)
        world_pos = (player.pos_x, player.pos_y)
        player.movement()
        player.interaction()

        player_rect = pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)

        for tile in sprite_list:
            if player_rect.colliderect(tile):
                (player.x, player.y) = player_pos
                (player.pos_x, player.pos_y) = world_pos
                print("hit!")
                player.frames = 0

        for doors in door_list:
            if player.interact.colliderect(doors):
                print("Interaction is working")
                scenes.sceneNum += 1

        for trees in tree_list:
            if player.interact.colliderect(trees):
                print("Tree!")

        door.draw()
        # Sprites.grass.draw()
        tree.draw()
        player.animation()
        player.draw()

    def Scene_2(self):
        window.fill(black)
        window.blit(world, (player.pos_x, player.pos_y))
        world.blit(background[1], (0,0))

        player_pos = (player.x, player.y)
        world_pos = (player.pos_x, player.pos_y)
        player.x, player.y = 718, 1223
        player.pos_x, player.pos_y = -238,-871

        player.movement()
        player.interaction()

        player_rect = pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)
        for trees in tree_list:
            if player_rect.colliderect(trees):
                (player.x, player.y) = player_pos
                (player.pos_x, player.pos_y) = world_pos

                print("Tree!")
                player.frames = 0
        tree.amount()
        player.animation()
        player.draw()

    def Draw_Scene(self):
        if self.sceneNum == 1:
            self.Scene_1()
        elif self.sceneNum == 2:
            self.Scene_2()


scenes = Scene()

running = True
while running:
    start_time = time.time()
    scenes.Draw_Scene()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), RESIZABLE)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if player.keys:
                player.frames = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_e or pygame.K_x:
                player.interact = pygame.Rect(-10, -10, 5, 5)
    print(player.x,player.y,player.pos_y,player.pos_x)
    (clock.tick(60))
    text = font.render("FPS " + str(int(1.0 / (time.time() - start_time))), True, blue)
    window.blit(text, (30, 20))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: which loop are you referring to?

Comment: its the main/only loop its all the way at the bottom when it says running = True

Comment: where are you changing scenes?

Comment: Right above it where the class Scene exists in scene one which is where the game starts has a door when the player interacts with door it changes scenes

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  This code contains a lot of overhead unrelated to the problem, and you haven't provided any tracking output for diagnostic help.

Comment: You should try to decouple the interactions from the scenes. But for now, how about a case  statement. if scene switches, depending on which scene, update the player position

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. If I enter the door ("e"), then the scene changes and the player is still moving.

Comment: oh sorry I accidently gave you a working one sorry!

Comment: Im very sorry guys I actually gave one without the issue, now the issue is here at the scene class where player.x , player.y and also player.posx, and posy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this would help, but divide the loop in to other loops, and when you want to change scenes, break the first one

Comment: That does sound like one way of fixing the issue but I think there is a different way of handling it making a new loop could become messy and I rather avoid that.

Comment: That is true, you could try keeping it all in one loop, and have each section under an if stament so that when you change variable x, it stops using and changes to the other. Something along the lines of while True: if x == 0: Scene 1, if x == 2: Scene 2

Comment: thanks that did it, I simply made it update on the first scene with the if statement instead of updating it on the new scene!